# How to make Doctrine use a MySQL TIMESTAMP column instead of DATETIME?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I'm looking for a way to use the MySQL `timestamp` column type in Doctrine 1.0. I was able to get it working by modifying `Doctrine_DataDict_Mysql` to return `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME` when the specified type is `timestamp`, but I'm fairly certain that it's not the right way, and it will probably break at some point.

Doctrine 2.0 seems to come with a built-in type mapping facility, but I can't find an equivalent mechanism in 1.0, and I'm kind of stuck with it for now.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to use TIMESTAMP instead of DATETIME?

Comment: Because my app is not the only app accessing the database, so while the actAs Timestampable behaviour would make automatic time stamping work for my app, a TIMESTAMP column would make it work for all apps (MySQL updates TIMESTAMP columns automatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably have better luck with this question on the [Doctrine IRC channel or Google group](http://www.doctrine-project.org/community); this is an extremely domain-specific question (which is okay), and there are surely more experts on the subject at one of those forums than here.

Chances are, though, you'll have to look at the source and do extensive testing to see what effects this will have.  On the bright side, it looks like Doctrine has [an extensive set of test cases](http://trac.doctrine-project.org/browser/trunk/tests/Doctrine/Tests), so you should be able to automate most if not all of this testing.

Comment: You're probably right. I'll take a look at the test cases, and try hitting the IRC channel. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hey.. I would be very interested in what you found out over there. It's not very satisfying to find an "accepted" answer here which is not really the answer to the question.. @Rytmis, would you care to post what you found out?